# Using for loop increments in a method

Tags: java, methods

I am trying to use a method to print a random number multiple times using increments. The problem is I don't seem to understand methods very well. I have no problem doing it otherwise but when I try to do it by calling a method I can't get any return and my console just remains blank. Here is what I have so far:

```
package WayBack;

import java.util.Random;

public class Review {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    {
        method1();
    }

    public String method1()
    {
        String rv = "";
        for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            int number = r.nextInt((100) - 0) * 100;
            System.out.println("your number is " + number);
        }
        return rv;
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated
Thank You

Comment: You need to actually call `method1()` from within your `main()`.  That anonymous pair of braces you have the call in now is an *instance initializer*; no instance of class `Review` ever gets created, so it never gets a chance to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invoke the `method1` function in `main`. But your `method1` function is an instance method. So you should new an Instance of the `Review` class, and then invoke the method1 function.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Review instance = new Review();
    instance.method1();
}
```

Or, You can declare the `method1` as `static` so that you can call it directly in the `main` method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    method1();
}
public static String method1()
{
    String rv = "";
    for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int number = r.nextInt((100) - 0) * 100;
        System.out.println("your number is " + number);
    }
    return rv;
}
```

An other way, you can invoke the method1 in the `constructor` of the `Review` class. And If you create an instance of a class, the methods in the `constructor` of the class are automatically called. In this way, you don't have necessary to invoke your method in the `main`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Review instance = new Review(); // it will call the method1 automatically
}
public Review() {
    // invoke your method
    method1();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are not calling the method `method1`. It is not wrapped in `Main`, instead it is wrapped in a set of floating curly braces.

```
package WayBack;

import java.util.Random;

public class Review {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    method1(); // put it here

}

// This block is not executed
{
method1();
}

public String method1()
{
String rv = "";
for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
{
Random r = new Random();
int number = r.nextInt((100) - 0) * 100;
System.out.println("your number is " + number);
}    return rv;
}
}
```

Comment: `method1` is  also an instance method.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone is pointing out, you need to include `method1()` inside your `main`.
The reason for this is because Java starts all programs in `public static void main(String[] args)` from here it reads one line at a time inside the block of code. A block of code is defined as what is in the '{' and '}', often called braces.

Because the `main` method is ALWAYS static, and you cannot reference non-static things inside a static method, you will either need to change your `method1` to also be static or create an object that can reference the method. You will learn about this later on.

For now,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    method1();
}

public static String method1() {
    String rv = "";
    Random r = new Random(); //this 'r' object only needs to be created once.
    for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
    {
         int number = r.nextInt(100) * 100; // you were subtracting 0 for no reason?
         System.out.println("your number is " + number);
         rv = rv + number + ", "; //rv is empty in your example, this will fill it with the 5 numbers generated. (It's not perfect)
    }
    return rv;
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the line  ' rv = rv + number + ", " '. I took away the ", " and it still worked properly but I cant understand why the line is needed in the first place and why it needs + number in there. Could you please explain. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm assuming that `rv` stands for "return valueS", given that you are getting 5 of them with your for loop. With that assumption, a basic walk down. Method definitions have a few key parts, modifiers (key words like public, static, etc), return type (void, String, Object, int, etc), method name (main, method1, nextInt, println, etc), and the parameters (things in the parentheses such as: args, (100) - 0, "your number is " + number).

You gave method1 the return type of "String" with `public static STRING method1()`, thus you have to return a string type back to the calling methods.

Comment: `rv` was empty, so I thought what you would be looking for was to give it some values. Nothing changes in your original program however if you were to say do `String valuesFromMethod1 = method1();` where `method1()` is, and then print valuesFromMethod1, you will see that you have access to the values, in a string format outside of method1.

So this could allow you to do something like `public static void main(String[] args) { System.out.println("Your numbers are " + method1()); }`  <- I would actually encourage this, without modifying method1's code so you can learn how things are executed.

Comment: Thank you very much. You explained it well. That was a big help.

Answer (score 0):

Your rv variable return an empty value.

You can create a class(MyClass) where in future you can Add other methods:
 For example you can do:

```
package WayBack; 
import java.util.Random; 

public class Review {

  public static void main(String[] args) { 
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   public MyClass work=new MyClass();

    work.method1();

  } 
 } 
//---create an other file and write this one    
 Public Class MyClass{

   private String rv;
   private int number;
   private Random r;

  //constructor
  public MyClass(){

    this.number=0;
    this.rv="";
    this. r= new Random();

   }

  public String method1() { 

    for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) { 

     number = r.nextInt((100) - 0) * 100;
     System.out.println("your number is "+number);
      rv=rv+number+","; } 
      return rv; } 
}//end MyClass
```

Answer (score 0):

Since 'method1' is called in a block, this will execute at the time when you create the object.

```
{
    method1();
}
```

**You only have to create the object in the main method.** No need to make method static.

Try this,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Review review = new Review();
}
```

Comment: Such construct is called an **instance initialization block**.